# How to select node by ID in bootstrap tree view?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, treeview

How to select node by ID in bootstrap tree view?
I use bootstrap treeview and fill data by json. I want to search in the tree by ID or data-nodeid attribute in it.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a coding service. If you have a specific problem in programming then you can ask your question here with an example of your code. [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2):

```
function selectNodeById(id){
    var treeViewObject = $('#tree').data('treeview'),
    allCollapsedNodes = treeViewObject.getCollapsed(),
    allExpandedNodes = treeViewObject.getExpanded(),
    allNodes = allCollapsedNodes.concat(allExpandedNodes);
    for (var i = 0; i < allNodes.length; i++) {
        if (allNodes[i].id != id) continue;
        treeViewObject.selectNode(allNodes[i].nodeId);
    }
}
```